# Postgres db deleting parent table row NOT deleting child table row data?

Tags: java, postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have a postgres database that I didn't design, but I have some tables that have Foreign Keys (FK) that reference the primary keys (PK) of some other tables. I have a draw up a nice little diagram to showcase this:

[image]

So you can see I have (3) three schemas, and they would have normal names but to make this example dumbed-down/simple, I have just called them **schema1**, **schema2**, and **schema3**. Now, **table A** for example, has (3) three foreign keys, which reference *table B*, *table D*, and **table E** directly.

The behavior I expected from research/googling was that if you delete the Parent table (the table having the Primary key which the Foreign Key in child table references), then the Child table row deletion should follow automatically.

I wasn't see this behavior - that is, if I delete a record from **table A** which references (3) three other tables (table B, table D, and table E), the record from table A is deleted but all the records in the other tables stay.

I want to be able to delete records in the most simplistic way and have all the other tables that are referenced automatically delete as-well. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependent rows are not automatically deleted; the default action is to throw an error if deleting a row would make the database inconsistent.

If you want dependent rows to be deleted, you have to define the foreign key constraints with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: "Parent table (the table having the Foreign Key, or is it the other way around?)" It is the other way around. The FK goes into the child table. In your diagram tables B, D, E are independent(Parent) and tables A and C are dependent (child) tables. TableA has 3 parents. What is the meaning of *n* on the diagram, perhaps it indicates null is valid for that column, if so you would **not** delete the child but set the FK to Null; define FK as *on delete set null*.

Comment: I think the "n" was for the 1-to-many relationship of the table ("n" representing many, since n can be n=1, n=2 , n=3, ...n=99 and so forth).

Answer (score 1):

I think that in the conventional vocabulary, table E is the parent and table A is the child.  You seem to describe that backwards.

There are 5 different actions you can define to be taken then deleting from the parent ([documented here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html)), but none that apply when deleting from the child.  No such feature exists.